# Null pointer exception in REST Api in spring hibernate and jersey

Tags: hibernate, rest, spring-mvc

I have web application in spring hibernate and i want to create new webservices using these, i used Jersey all is fine but when i call from rest client it throw null pointer exception

```
        @RequestMapping(value="/login1.html",method=RequestMethod.GET)
            @ResponseBody
            public String login1(@ModelAttribute("command") LoginModel loginmodel, BindingResult result,ModelMap model,HttpServletRequest request)
            {
                String jsonResult="";
                //System.out.println("New One"+user_email);
                try{
                    System.out.println("Before");
                    LoginModel found = loginservice.login(loginmodel.getUser_email(), loginmodel.getUser_pass());

                    System.out.println("Here"+found.getSchool_id());


                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return jsonResult;
            }
```

Response

```
            Before
            "test_admin@mailinator.com"
            "test_admin@mailinator.com"--"123456"
            Hibernate: select loginmodel0_.user_id as user1_6_, loginmodel0_.contact_number as contact2_6_, loginmodel0_.school_id as school3_6_, loginmodel0_.user_email as user4_6_, loginmodel0_.user_name as user5_6_, loginmodel0_.user_pass as user6_6_, loginmodel0_.user_role as user7_6_ from tbl_users loginmodel0_ where loginmodel0_.user_email='"test_admin@mailinator.com"'
            null
            java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: 1.) Looks like `found` is null in `System.out.println("Here"+found.getSchool_id());`.
2.) Looks like your email and password parameters strings actually contain quotes which they probably should not and which would explain why no user is found.

Comment: Thanks you  @rostbot  you was right and it is working now, but i used it from controller of spring then it works when i use it from class for jersey it again same problem even i removed quotes.  Autowires Annotation is not working in this class, is it possible to use same dao for this class